# wordpress list child pages, show their content without refreshing whole page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, parent-child, page-refresh

I have kind of a logical question here...

Is it possible to list (and link, of course) all child pages of the page I'm on in the sidebar and show their respective content in the main-content area without refreshing the whole page (ajax-kind of style?)

If so, could you point me the right direction, please?
I'm thinking about hardcoding the list of child pages output into the sidebar.php file and then define some functions...

Comment: Yes this is possible, i would list out the pages/post in the sidebar. Then onclick ajax in that content, using the wp built in ajax hooks. For added SEO support, possible look into html history api. Unfortunately it would be difficult to point you in the right direction, or give an example here.

Comment: does that method hurt SEO?

Comment: no as the posts still exist on there own individual indexable pages, more info http://pjax.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

It will hurt your seo ofc.. but you can ajax your contents from a custom wordpress template
that will only pull out PLAIN contents

and as for ajax it will then return the echo results and put them in a div that currently exist on your site.

```
$(".ajaxgetstuff").click(function(){
                $( ".result_div" ).show();
                $.post( %the_url_you_want_to_display%, {
                    postprams_values:"True",
                                        anyamountofPostValues:56
                }).done(function( data ) {
                    $( ".result_div" ).html( data );
                });
            });
```